# JQuery Cycle Plugin doesn't show text overlay in IE8

Tags: jquery, plugins, text, internet-explorer-8, cycle

Let me start by saying how I am a beginner at web designing, so my code and website may be a bit messy (although I try to do a clean job).

I have successfully added the JQuery Cycle Plugin to the homepage of my website, which looks great in Chrome, Firefox, and even works in IE9 when I accept the add-ons. But, when I tested it on IE8 no plug-in was asked to load, and it shows the text it show's it in regular font in black, which cannot be seen because the background is also black.

I assume the problem lies somewhere within IE8 and the CSS file, although I am not entirely sure. I'm hoping there's a fix for this.

jquery-1.3.1.min.js

Here is my code:

```
<div id="data" style="position: absolute; left: -12px; top: 237px; width: 775px; height: 556px; z-index: 11">

<div id="layer8" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 3px; width: 760px; height: 456px; z-index: 17">

        <div id="gallery">
<a href="#" class="show">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_1.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intro>Great Neck - A Community of Luxury Homes</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_2.jpg" alt="Grass Blades" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intros>SEEK THE BEST</h3intros><h3intro>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KNOWLEDGE...</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_3.jpg" alt="Ladybug" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intros>SEEK THE BEST</h3intros><h3intro>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;INTEGRITY...</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_4.jpg" alt="Lightning" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intros>SEEK THE BEST</h3intros><h3intro>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE...</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_5.jpg" alt="Lotus" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intro>We love what we sell...</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_6.jpg" alt="Mojave" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intro>And only sell what we love...</h3intro>"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/intro/Slide_7.jpg" alt="Pier" width="997" height="532" title="" alt="" rel="<h3intros>FIND&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3intros><h3intro>JANET ETESSAMI REALTY</h3intro>"/>
</a>

            <div class="caption">

                <div class="content">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clear">
        </div>

</div>
```

Through this, any chance I could be directed to exactly what code I should be putting?

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head against the wall for the last few hours also and saw your post.  Adding z-index to both the overlay css element and the slideshow container fixed it for me.

Example:

Add the higher z-index number for the overlay CSS class.
Use a lower z-index number for the CSS container for the slideshow.

```
<style>
.overlay-css 
{ 
   your css
   z-index: 4; 
}
.slideshow { 
   your css
   z-index: 3; 
}
</style>

<div id="slideshow-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay-css">This is the text that appears over the slideshow.</div>    
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="test-1"/>
        <img src="image2.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="test-2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```